# Как работать с JSON полями в PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, postgresql

У меня есть `SQL` запрос к базе данных, который мне нужно переписать на `PostgreSQL`.

`select detailsJson from VoucherBatchTransaction WHERE JSON_VALUE(VoucherBatchTransaction.detailsJson, '$.transferToken') != 'fake_token';`

Этот запрос работает и выводит мне все поля где `transferToken` **НЕ** равен `fake_token`.

Мне нужно переписать этот запрос на `PostgreSQL`. И что я только не перепробовал. Сначала я попробовал просто вывести значения этого поля, и это сработало.

`select voucherbatchtransaction.detailsjson -> 'transferToken' from voucherbatchtransaction;`

Но вот дальше этого не пошло. То есть запрос по типу этого, не работает:

`select voucherbatchtransaction.detailsjson -> 'transferToken' ->> 'fake_token' from voucherbatchtransaction;`

Что я делаю не так и как можно переписать этот запрос?

Comment: *запрос по типу этого, не работает* Вы посмотрите, как правильно пишутся JSON-пути, что ли... https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH и https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на документацию, разобрался, но не могли бы вы подсказать как добавить к этому логическое отрицание, чтобы было где **НЕ** `fake_token`, `voucherbatchtransaction.detailsjson::jsonb @> '{"transferToken": "fake_token"}'`

Comment: Нет, это не работает `SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: json <> unknown`. А вот то, что я написал выше - работает, мне просто нужно добавить к этому логическое отрицание

Comment: Да, опечатался. `(voucherbatchtransaction.detailsjson ->> 'transferToken') != 'fake_token'`. Вечно путаю, какая из операций `->` и `->>` возвращает строку.

Comment: Логическое отрицание для выражения `A` будет `not (A)`.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Безумно Вам благодарен, всё работает. А по поводу того, что `not` это ключевое слово для отрицания - тут моя ошибка, я забыл уточнить, что это выражение только чистый пример и оно используется в других запросах, поэтому по этим причинам я не могу просто добавить `not`